# grails : not fetching / listing data from database

Tags: mysql, grails, select

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code. I think I've followed the tutorials correctly but mine won't work. What I need  to do is to list the data from db. 
Here's my code.

Controller..

```
class DailyProfitController {
    def scaffold = DailyProfit
    def index() { 
        render(view:"profitTable");
    }

    def save() {
       // Date myDate = params.date('test', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        params.date_month = (Integer.parseInt(params.date_month)<10)? "0" + params.date_month : params.date_month;
        params.date_day = (Integer.parseInt(params.date_day)<10)? "0" + params.date_day : params.date_day;
        params.date = params.date_year + "-" + params.date_month + "-" + params.date_day
        def dailyProfit = new DailyProfit(params)
        println params.toString();
        dailyProfit.save()
        render(view:"profitTable");

    }

    def list(){
        def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list()
        [dailyProfit:dailyProfit]
        render(view:"profitTable");
    }

}
```

HTML

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Profit</th>
                          <th>Delete?</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>             <g:each in="${dailyProfit}" var="dailyProfit">
                <tr>
                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${dailyProfit.date}">${dailyProfit.date}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${dailyProfit.profit}</td>
                                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                </tr>           </g:each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And this is the log from hibernate:

> Hibernate: select this_.date as date0_0_, this_.profit as profit0_0_
>   from daily_profit this_

Comment: Why not let grails tell you what your code should look like (especially if you're just picking up the framework)? Look into the  "grails generate-all" command. Then review the generated code; controllers, and views. Very instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong :

```
def list(){
        def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list()
        [dailyProfit:dailyProfit] 
        render(view:"profitTable");
}
```

Correct :

```
def list(){
        def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list()
        render view:"profitTable",  model: [dailyProfit : dailyProfit]
    }
```

Do let me know if it worked.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I've tried it already but it still isn't working. What else do you you have in mind that might be the reason why it isn't working? And what does this code mean by the way [dailyProfit : dailyProfit] Thank you :)

Comment: just an update, i changed the code of list action to this just to check if it is fetching the data. And the output is 3. meaning it did get the data but maybe the problem has something to do with the rendering. or my html probably. thanks :)     def list(){
        def dailyProfit = DailyProfit.list()
        int noOfResources = dailyProfit.size()
        render noOfResources
       // render view:"profitTable",  model: [dailyProfit : dailyProfit]
    }

Comment: Aside from the changes above, what completely fixed the issue is when I changed the var name <g:each in="${dailyProfit}" var="dailyProfit"> . So basically, they identifier used in "in" should be different from the identifer used in "var". I don't know the explanation, but that fixed my problem :)

Comment: it was because two variable name cannot be same...that's why it was not getting any data.

Comment: and the render line that i changed means that when you are rendering any view than the data need to be passed is included in the model block not before or after it.